# RxJava how to emmit object from list with interval

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to emits objects from list with 1 sec interval.

```
AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.from(actionButtonList))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .flatMap(ab -> Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(ab).delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnEach(notification -> ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(notification.getValue(), "alpha", 1, 0).setDuration(500).start())
    .subscribe(ab -> Log.d(TAG, ab.toString()));
```

With this approach doOnEach is executed at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip a timer with your list:

```
Observable
.timer(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).onBackpressureDrop()
.zipWith(actionButtonList, (t, b) -> b)
.subscribeOn(...)
.observeOn(...)
.doOnNext(...)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: As timer has been deprecated, you can use interval.